# Passing key and pem file data in curl command not working

Tags: bash, api, shell, curl, sh

I am trying to invoke the API using the `curl` command but unfortunately, I won't be able to keep the files. I am trying to pass the `.key` and `.pem` file's data in the command but I am not able to pass that correctly. Below is my command in my `.sh` file:

```
response=$(curl --key "$5" --cert "$6" -k -X "$2" -d "$payload" "$4")
```

I am calling the script below way:

```
key="${key}"
pem="${pem}"

bash ./Integration1.sh Provision POST "$payload" https://some-api.com/pr "$key" "$pem"
```

It gives the below error:

```
curl: (58) could not load PEM client certificate from -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

This command works fine if I pass the file directly so, is there any way to pass the data via string variables in the curl command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have your key data in a variable and can't write it to a file yourself for some reason, an alternative solution is to use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

```
bash ./Integration1.sh Provision POST "$payload" https://some-api.com/pr \
<(printf '%s' "$key") \
<(printf '%s' "$pem")
```

This requires bash and still uses files under the hood, but it doesn't require you to manage the files yourself or know where they're located.

Comment: Yes, I tried writing the key string to a `.key` file like this `cat "${CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_KEY}" > ./client.key` but it raised an error `cat: unrecognized option '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` so I will try your answer now.

Comment: `cat` reads files  and echos their content.  you want `echo` for that kind of command @whatsinthename

Answer (score 1):

[`--key` and `--cert` take the name of a *file* containing certificate data](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html), not the certificate data itself.

```
... "$(cat my_client.key)" "$(cat my_client.pem)"
```

Should just be

```
... my_client.key my_client.pem
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to store the contents of the `key` and `pem` in a string and when I ran the statement with `... "$key" "$pem"` it gave me this error `curl: (58) could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:02001024:system library:fopen:File name too long, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)`

Comment: To add more to the context, I have stored the key and pem value as the GitLab variable and trying to access in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file where I am creating two variables like `key=${key-variable}` and `pem=${pem-variable}`

Comment: If you're storing the key and cert in string variables you should put that in your question. It changes the problem a lot if you only have variables with data in them and not files like your original example.